# TravicCI build dont find Managa.py [Django] command

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

im following a tutorial and a complete newbie. 
in the tutorial the tutor used docker as virtual envioremnt and because im currently using my Win-10-Home machine i've decided to use plain 'ol `python venv`.

for some reason TravicCI is not fiding my manage.py command, and i cant figure out why!

this is the TCI log

```
0.58s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/therealgenish/recipe-app-api.git  therealgenish/recipe-app-api
$ source ~/virtualenv/python3.6/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 3.6.7
$ pip --version
  pip 19.0.3 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.7/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
  install
$ pip install -r requirments.txt
$ app\manage.py test && flake8
appmanage.py: command not found
The command "app\manage.py test && flake8" exited with 127.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

the reason it's `app\manage.py` and not `manage.py` is because it's outside the app folder, so i figured..

the `.travis.yaml` :

```
language: python
python:
 - 3.6

install:
 - pip install -r requirments.txt

script:
 - app\manage.py test && flake8
```

and a [link to the github project](https://shorturl.at/bEIJ1)

Comment: Try a forward slash - `app/manage.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$ cd app/ && python manage.py test && flake8
```

Because you first need to navigate to app with `manage.py` file.

Answer (score 1):

turns out to be a simple syntax problem
-- travis needed help with where the `manage.py` file is

solution:

`script:
 - cd app/ && python manage.py test && flake8`